# lodash orderby alphabetically with numbers in the string

Tags: lodash

I would like to order the following array:

- name: 2014 Autumn Grth 10
- name: 2014 Autumn Grth 4
- name: 2014 Autumn Grth 5
- name: 2014 Autumn Ethical Balanced
- name: 2014 Autumn Grth 6
- name: 2014 Autumn Grth 7
- name: 2014 Summer Grth 7
- name: 2014 Autumn Grth 9

If I do the following:

```
_.orderBy(list, function (e) { return e.name, ['desc'] })
```

It will return:

- 2014 Autumn Ethical Balanced
- 2014 Autumn Grth 10
- 2014 Autumn Grth 4
- 2014 Autumn Grth 5
- 2014 Autumn Grth 6
- 2014 Autumn Grth 7
- 2014 Autumn Grth 9
- 2014 Summer Grth 7

As you can see it alphabetically orders the list correctly but doesn't take the number at the end of the string into account.

Much appreciated for your help :)

Comment: `function (e) { return e.name, ['desc'] }` is completely bonkers.

Comment: Need to move that to: `(function (e) { return e.name }, ['desc'])`

Comment: Can't believe that typo!!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to sort your array by specifying the `numeric` option as `true`.

```js
var data = [{name: '2014 Autumn Grth 10'},{name: '2014 Autumn Grth 4'},{name: '2014 Autumn Grth 5'},{name: '2014 Autumn Ethical Balanced'},{name: '2014 Autumn Grth 6'},{name: '2014 Autumn Grth 7'},{name: '2014 Summer Grth 7'},{name: '2014 Autumn Grth 9'}];
var result = data.slice().sort((a,b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name, undefined, {numeric: true}));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Good point, there is no need for lodash at all. But you should copy the array to preserve the clean semantics of `_.orderBy` and because it makes the code easier to reason about.

Comment: Thanks a million guys, you're a life saver!!

Comment: It makes sense to use native sort, but PO was asking lodash solution